# Android Wear OS app is not visible on the play store

Tags: android, wear-os, watchapp

I have published my Android Wear OS app on the play store. It is submitted but not visible on the Wear OS watches.

Comment: Wait for few days . I had this issue for normal apps , they wont be visible in search for few days .

Comment: It's been more than a month and still not visible.

Comment: Does your production track shows how many regions? Say 177 countries / regions?

Comment: Yes it's showing all 177 countries. Currently my phone app is latest and that includes the watch app